# Error on reading .ini file -> Parsing error: Key name is not valid

Tags: c#, ini, parse-error

I am actually reading several .ini files in a loop from a console application.
All of them is being read correctly except one.

Find my piece of code below;

```
 var parser = new IniParser.FileIniDataParser();
 string DBPath;

 foreach (IniParser.KeyData i in dbList)
 {
    DBPath = "C:\\Program Files\Test\Database.ini";              
    IniData dbConn = parser.LoadFile(DBPath);
```

However, I am having the following error on the last line;

```
"Parsing error: Key name is not valid"
```

The thing is that all of the .ini files resemble each other, and all the other is working fine.
Anyone can guide me as to why this error occurs and how can I fix it please.

Find below the stack trace;

```
 at IniParser.StreamIniDataParser.ReadData(StreamReader reader, Boolean relaxedIniFormat)
   at IniParser.FileIniDataParser.LoadFile(String fileName, Boolean relaxedIniRead)
   at IniParser.FileIniDataParser.LoadFile(String fileName)
   at ReadIniFile.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\mkorumta\Desktop\ReadIniFile\ReadIniFile\Program.cs:line 33
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**EDIT:**

According to some more investigation, I found out that the .ini file is raising the error because of the Key name `[AAO-4 Data]`, where the `space` seem to be the culprit. Any idea how to avoid this error. Note that the ini file is generic and cannot be modified. I need to modify my code to be able to read the file.

How do I force the code to ignore the space?

Comment: I'm guessing that the key name is not valid. If you want a more specific answer, you'll probably need to narrow down the problem. Remove stuff from the .ini file until you find the problem. You'll probably solve this yourself. If that doesn't do it, come back with more info.

Comment: what do you mean by key name not valid? I am reading a series of .ini files and all of them is being read correctly, only for this one. and the content is almost the same for all .ini file. I'm expecting some more info about the error.. Googling not helping much!

Comment: Too few data for pointing out the exact issue. But at least your DBPath is incorrect. Should be "C:\\Program Files\\Test\\Database.ini" or @"C:\Program Files\Test\Database.ini".

Comment: It doesn't help to think "the content is almost the same". Obviously it's NOT the same. Just figure out what's wrong with the .ini file, and fix it. You gave no relevant information in this question.

Comment: @tenfour Updated the question after some more investigation.

Comment: This is open source library right? Then fix it...

Comment: @leppie I don;t get you, what do I need to fix?

Comment: Maybe just find another library for ini parsing. Or write your own. Or patch the library you're using. Or patch the ini file before parsing it.

Comment: @tenfour in fact it's the space in the section name that is causing the error. any idea how can I force ignore the space?

Comment: Hi, looking at the stack trace I think I'm the creator of the library you are using: https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser/ Could you post the version you are using? The latest version does support whitespaces inside a section's name, so you should upgrade it. If you still have problems, could you please fill a github issue with the steps to reproduce the problem?